# Integral with $e$ , $ \int e^{x^3}\;dx$

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

$ \int e^{x^3}\;dx$
  so, i'm searching for answer this question, i think that this not is too easily, but i think this integral not exist solution undefined, this integral would be easy if  had the derivative out but i'snt happen

Comment: Maple says this here

Comment: $-1/3\, \left( -1 \right) ^{2/3} \left( 2/3\,{\frac {x\sqrt [3]{-1}\pi 
\,\sqrt {3}}{\Gamma  \left( 2/3 \right) \sqrt [3]{-{x}^{3}}}}-{\frac {
x\sqrt [3]{-1}\Gamma  \left( 1/3,-{x}^{3} \right) }{\sqrt [3]{-{x}^{3}
}}} \right) 
$

Comment: WA gives a simpler answer $$\frac{-x\Gamma\left(\frac13,-x^3\right)}{3\sqrt[3]{-x^3}}$$ which by hand reduces to $$\frac13\Gamma\left(\frac13,-x^3\right)$$

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

There is no [elementary function,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) say $\mathrm{f}$, with the property that
$$\frac{\mathrm{df}}{\mathrm{d}x}=\mathrm{e}^{x^3}$$

Comment: The power in this question is $3$, not $2$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$I=\int\exp(x^3)\,\mathrm dx$$
Let $t=-x^3$
$$I=-\frac13\int t^{-2/3}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm dt$$

The lower incomplete gamma function is defined as
$$\gamma(a,x)=\int_0^x t^{a-1}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm dt$$
Since when $a=1/3$ this integral is just the required integral with a fixed constant, we can assign.
$$I=-\frac13\gamma\left(\frac13, -x^3\right)+\color{gray}{\text{constant}}$$
However the lower incomplete gamma function is not so widely used, but since the incomplete gamma function is defined as
$$\Gamma(a,x)=\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm dt$$
Therefore it's true by definition that
$$\gamma(a,x)+\Gamma(a,x)=\Gamma(a)$$
$$\gamma(a,x)=\Gamma(a)-\Gamma(a,x)$$
We can therefore rewrite
$$I=-\frac13\left(\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)-\Gamma\left(\frac13, -x^3\right)\right)+\color{gray}{\text{constant}}$$
Which reduces to
$$I=\frac13\Gamma\left(\frac13, -x^3\right)-\frac13\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)+\color{gray}{\text{constant}}$$
However since $-\frac13\Gamma(1/3)$ is a constant, this reduces to the following where the constant is another value
$$I=\frac13\Gamma\left(\frac13, -x^3\right)+\color{gray}{\text{constant}}$$

See [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html) for more information on the functions $\gamma(a,x)$ and $\Gamma(a,x)$

Answer (score -2):

the function of $\int e^{x^2} dx$ is undefined.
most likely the function of $e^{x^3}$ is also undefined.
there exists a error function ($erf$) which approximates the integral
you can read more over that here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Just because they are similar does not mean that this one is unable to be represented easily. Also please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1)

Comment: Sorry i am new to this. i will do that in advance!